# Delete all questions closed as duplicate of deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

When a question is deleted, any questions that are closed as a duplicate of that question should also be deleted. This should be a rule at least on regular sites. Meta sites could be a little different, since duplicates on metas may not be *exact* duplicates, but problems arising from that will constitute such an edge case that they're probably not worth handling specially.

*This post originally asked what to do with questions closed as duplicates of deleted questions, but I found ["Duplicate of...[deleted post]"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post) almost immediately after asking, so I have reworked it to request the feature Shog9 suggested in an answer there.*

Comment: If the question ends up being undeleted, will the dupes be restored? (If not, why not?) Also, maybe we need to special-case questions with zero or one non-upvoted answers, since the owner's deletion vote is binding in that case.

Comment: perhaps they could also consider alternative approach of simply auto-reopening rather than auto-delete

Comment: @ConradFrix Auto-reopening probably wouldn't work. If the "original" question was deleted, it was likely off-topic or otherwise unsuitable. Its duplicates would therefore also be unsuitable and reopening them without review could be problematic.

Comment: @ConradFrix, if you check this question's revision history, you'll see that I considered auto-reopen. I decided against suggesting it for the reasons Anna gave. You could make the case that _some_ questions on meta sites might deserve reopening rather than deletion, but that's what I'm calling an edge case.

Comment: @AnnaLear well if you insist on review before auto-reopen then I would hope you would want review before auto-delete

Comment: @Conrad, questions closed as duplicates usually have little value (besides a link to the more "canonical" question, which I do agree can be useful to provide an alternate search path to that question and its answers). They're merged otherwise. However, auto-deleting only removes that alternate path, so reviewing is probably not that important. Back to your point, since there can be multiple duplicates targeting the same question, *which one* would you reopen when the target question is deleted?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi perhaps once a question has been marked as the target of a dup it shouldn't be allowed to be deleted unless the mod repoints the other dups or deletes the other refs, rather than cascading the delete or reopen

Comment: @ConradFrix I'm not a fan of the deletion proposal either, to be honest, but if a question is a duplicate and the original is deleted, is there any need to keep the duplicate? I dunno.