# On deletion of a question, find and kill the duplicates as well

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete all questions closed as duplicate of deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109647/delete-all-questions-closed-as-duplicate-of-deleted-questions)

I was digging around MSO for info about SE 1.0, and I came across [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82916/list-of-stack-exchange-1-0-sites). It was marked as a dupe of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40784/is-this-a-stack-exchange-website), which was deleted.

Can we do *something* about posts that point to deleted posts as dupes? I'm fine with deleting the dupes (or giving mods the option). I'm also fine with relaxing the deletion policy for posts that have dupes pointing to them. It's just nonsensical to have a post closed as a dupe point to a deleted one.

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Obligatory: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lI3Am.jpg

Comment: @animuson: [Why not?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/132474/2)

Comment: @sha - make sure that dupe is not already deleted! ;)

Comment: @Lix lol! I sacrificed 50 rep to try and draw attention.. chances are slim, I recently spent nearly 1000 to no avail on some other stuff here.