# How many 'do not close' votes does it take to cancel a suggested duplicate?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

The SO question [PHP Query for iOS Latitude and Longitude not searching for nearby MySQL lat-and-long in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870803/php-query-for-ios-latitude-and-longitude-not-searching-for-nearby-mysql-lat-and) has a 'suggested duplicate' to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870967/issue-with-php-not-matching-lon-and-lat-from-ios-with-a-mysql-data-entry) (10k users) which has been deleted by the other question's original poster.

1. Why is this other question still being considered for closing as a duplicate of a deleted question?
2. How many people are going to have to waste their time saying 'Do Not Close'?  There are 4 so far who've done so.

Comment: Arguably, the new question also deserves deletion... But the OP is really trying, so it would feel very harsh.

Comment: @Pekka: and even if it should be closed as...well, something other than as a duplicate, it is clear (to me) that it should not be closed as a duplicate of a question that has been deleted before it was closed as a duplicate (it would be a separate matter if it was closed as a duplicate of a then visible question that was subsequently deleted).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 5 votes not to close, the question gets kicked from the queue and the existing close votes for it start aging, so:

- Those close votes will soon expire.
- No more users will view the question in the Close Votes queue based on those close votes.

[Explained in more detail by the Shog.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673)

---

As for duplicate votes to deleted questions, it's very rare and a vast majority of the time that question [should be deleted as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43727). There's really no point in trying to auto-detect it and destroy those votes.