# What should happen when the marked duplicate of a question is deleted?

Tags: discussion, bug, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2226504/1234256) (which has pending delete votes, but is still visible) was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419968/best-open-source-java-cms) (which has already been deleted).

The above is an example of when the duplicate system breaks. The `Possible Duplicate` banner is still present, but most users won't be able to see the linked question. [One comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226504/need-to-know-cms-with-java#comment21486618_2226504) even *recommended a scraper* that allowed them to view the question in (er...) question.

My question is **what should happen to questions like these?** Should the duplicate be unmarked? That may not be the best because in this case, *both* questions are off-topic and deserve deletion. What else could be done?

Comment: Related: [“Duplicate of…\[deleted post\]”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post) and [Auto-flag duplicates of deleted questions for reopening / deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221619/auto-flag-duplicates-of-deleted-questions-for-reopening-deletion)

Answer (score 1):

I propose that the duplicate be unmarked and the question added to the triage queue (where available) or the VLQ queue.

This will

- Remove links that are broken for the extreme majority of users. (On Stack Overflow, for one, [there are 3,322,570 users with rep > 0 and < 10,000](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow))
- Help remove low quality questions.

Comment: Not sure about automatic unmarking. For questions that need to be deleted, this means they get reopened just to be closed again (more work for the close queue), and then deleted.

Comment: @Fundamental But the question in question wouldn't be closed again the same way. And duplicates aren't necessarily bad questions.

Comment: @Mooseman That's true, but when a question is a duplicate of another, and that other question is a bad question, then it's a *very* compelling reason that the duplicate has the same, or similar, problems.  It's certainly *possible* for a good question to be a duplicate of a bad question, but its *much* less likely than a bad question being a duplicate of another bad question.

Comment: How about a cached version of that question?