# Cannot be deleted because of duplicate lean

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

I attempted to cast a delete vote on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167433/how-to-display-user-profiles-after-authentication). I got the error shown below:

[image]

I understand this to mean [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28232592/1234256) were closed as a duplicate of **this one**, but have a few questions:

1. How did it get 2 delete votes?
2. Why is there a "cancel" link when I could just use the <kbd>X</kbd>?
3. Should I custom-reason flag this, and if yes, what exactly should I say?

Comment: 1. It likely got delete votes before it was made a duplicate-target?

Comment: @J.Steen Makes sense. But I don't know if 20k users can delete at this point or not.

Comment: @Mooseman: 20k users get the same message.

Comment: This feature was broken for a long time. Glad they finally got it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239597/213575) is to prevent/cleanup duplicates that go to nowhere. The main objective is giving a <s>second</s> third chance to the closed duplicates to be evaluated on their own, remembering that if there's a question closed as duplicated of a closed question, is very likely that the duplicated would be closed as was the target was and [elective for deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43727/213575).

> How did it get 2 delete votes?

Before the feature was implemented, the delete votes were casted.

> Why is there a "cancel" link when I could just use the X?

Because only Windows don't have duality when comes to options.

> Should I custom-reason flag this, and if yes, what exactly should I say?

Why? There's no need of moderator intervention. If you can cast delete votes, you can also delete the duplicated questions and/or reopen them. So, what to do in such cases? Check out the duplicates that points to that question, delete or reopen as you see fit (reopen should be reserved for duplicates that wouldn't be closed by another reason) and start making your way out.