# When the merge master is deleted, shouldn't also the stub be deleted?

Tags: support, bug, moderator-tools, deleted-questions, merged-questions

I recently came across a question on chemistry.se I previously merged and noticed that the master of that merge was deleted as an "RemovedAbandonedClosed" ([10k chem.se](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42396/4945)). However, the merge stub was alive and well, but now pointing into nirvana. I deleted it now manually ([10k](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42465/4945)).

This is almost the same scenario, that was mentioned here: [Auto-flag duplicates of deleted questions for reopening / deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221619/260760)

In this case, the questions are identical, by the same user, hence the merge. It seems that the automatic remove does not pay attention to the linking of the questions, as a user would have to when casting a delete vote.
It seems the [majority of users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43724/260760) agree that a linked post should be deleted alongside the master.

This leads me to two questions and a suggestion:

- Have I performed the merge wrong? Should I have deleted the stub manually directly after the merge?
- Would the merge stub be deleted as abandoned closed, if I had not manually deleted it?
- Suggestion: Delete the stub, if the master gets deleted, too.

Comment: How old was the stub? I think they're supposed to be automatically deleted after 30 days.

Comment: @MadScientist Too young then, just mere 17 days.

Comment: Merged stubs are not deleted, migration stubs *are* deleted in 30 days. Cc @Martin-マーチン